# how Hide checkbox? toOptionArray()

Tags: magento2

> XML:

```
<item name="option">Vendor/Module/Source........</item>
(checkboxset)
```

> Vendor/Module/Source.........php

```
toOptionArray() 
{
return [
     [
        'value' => 'value', 'label' => 'label'
 ]
]
}
```

**How I can disabled field checkbox set if value and label == null ?

Or how I can return:**

> return  [    [
>       'value' => 'empty',    ] ]
>   without this input type='checkbox'

**ty**